# Webflux : Accumulate & details

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

I'm new to webflux and I'm trying to transform this code :

```
@Getter
public class Stock {
    private int value;
    private String productNumber;
    public Stock(int value, String productNumber){
        this.value = value;
        this.productNumber = productNumber;
    }
}


@Getter
public class StockResponse {
    private int value;
    private String productNumber;
    public StockResponse(int value, String productNumber){
        this.value = value;
        this.productNumber = productNumber;
    }
    public StockResponse(Stock stock){
        this.value = stock.getValue();
        this.productNumber = stock.getProductNumber();
    }

    public void add(int value){
        this.value += value;
    }
    
}

public List<StockResponse> findStockResponsesDetailsAndTotal() {
    List<StockResponse> stocksResponses = new ArrayList();
    List<Stock> stocks = stockRepository.findAll();
    StockResponse total = new StockResponse(0, "Total");
    stocks.forEach(stock -> {
        total.add(stock.getValue());
        stocksResponses.add(new StockResponse(stock));
    });
    stocksResponses.add(total);
    return stocksResponses;
}
```

into a "flux phylosophy"
Here is my code so far :

```
stockRepository.findAll()
  .map(StockResponse::convert)
```

I'm kinda lost about the "total", I know that I can do a reduce on the Flux but i'll lose all the details in doing so

Comment: could you show a code snippet for the StockResponse class? It's not clear why each stock is stored as a StockResponse instances and why there is another independent instance for the total amount.

Comment: StockResponse class contain a value of stock and a reference of product. The StockResponse is just a DTO because this method will be exposed to an UI

Comment: then this sample doesn't compile as `new StockResponse(0)` won't work for this record class

Comment: It was a simplified code, I may have slipped some typo errors, sorry, I've updated it and it should be ok now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it a bit odd to add the total result as the last element in the list instead of having a dedicated class containing the total on one side and the elements on the other).

But here's a code snippet anyway:

```
Mono<List<StockResponse>> responses = findAll()
    .map(StockResponse::new).collectList().map(allStock -> {
        StockResponse total = new StockResponse(0, "Total");
        allStock.forEach(stock -> total.add(stock.value));
        List<StockResponse> result = new ArrayList<>(allStock);
        result.add(total);
        return result;
});
```

Comment: I've finally adopt your proposition by creating another class with the details and a specific property for total